# Get child category id Mangeto 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-id

I have category structure like this.

1. Shirts:

   - Male.
   - Female.
2. Pents:

   - Male.
   - Female.

What I'm trying is get the category ID by giving passing the parameter like 'Petns/Male' or something like this. I spent an almost complete day to find a solution but didn't get any help.

Looking forward to Hint/Solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain in details so that we can understand easily to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below code Put in your phtml file. `@parentCategoryId` pass category id.

```
<?php
$categoryChild = Mage::helper('your_helper')->getCustomMenuCategory($parentCategoryId);
if (count($categoryChild) > 0) {
    ?>
    <div class="child-category">
        <ul class="child-subcategories">
            <?php foreach ($categoryChild as $child): ?>
                <li>                    
                    <a href="<?php echo $child->getUrl() ?>">
                        <span><?php echo $child->getName() ?></span></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and below in your helper

```
public function getCustomMenuCategory($categoryId) {

    try {            
            $categoryChild = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getChildrenCategories();
            if (count($categoryChild) > 0) {
                return $categoryChild;
            } else {
                $parentcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getParentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
                return $parentcategories;
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Mage::log($ex, null, 'subcategory.log');
    }
}
```

Hope this will work.
If this will work for you then accept it.