# How to get categorychildren in a list under topcategories

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

I want a list of categories with under each categoryname their children categories. But my code isn't working, the top categories are showing but

```
<ul class="sub"></ul>
```

is empty, so the children are not showing.

This is my code:

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('level',2)
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$out = "<ul>";
foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
    $children = $cat->getChildren();
    $out .= "<li>";
    $out .= "<b><a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a></b>";
        $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
        foreach($children as $child){
            $ChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
            $out .="<li><a href='".$ChildModel->getUrl()."'>".$ChildModel->getName()."</a></li>";
        }
        $out .="</ul>";
    $out .= "</li>";
}
$out .= "</ul>";
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code with your code:

```
$out .="<ul class='sub'>";
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($children->getId())->getChildrenCategories();

    foreach($children as $child){

        $out .="<li><a href='".$child->getUrl()."'>".$child->getName()."</a></li>";
    }
    $out .="</ul>";
```

**Edit this line:**

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId())->getChildrenCategories();
```

**[Edit]**

You want show only current product parent categories? right?

[click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170933/get-child-category-id-mangeto-1-9-2/170966#170966)

This may help you.

Comment: I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on string in `

Comment: I have edit answer please see

Comment: and remove `$children = $cat->getChildren();` this line

Comment: it's working or not? if working then accept answer and give upvote.

Comment: It shows all sub-categories from that category, how can I get only the sub categories that the product is in? The list is shown on the product view page. Also it shows all topcategories, I only need the categories from the current product.

Comment: Ok, I edit my answer please see that answer

Comment: what does `your_helper` mean?

Comment: Your helper class name.

Comment: So do I need to create a module for 1 function? @ARVIND KARKAR

Comment: You can add that function into any of your other custom module

Comment: alright so for example I edit the file IndexController.php inside local/Magik/Socialbar/controllers , do I then use this: `$categoryChild = Mage::helper('Magik/Socialbar/controllers/IndexController.php')->getCustomMenuCategory($parentCategoryId);` ?

Comment: I get this error when I do it like that: `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Magik_Helper_Socialbar' not found in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php on line 547`

Comment: No, you can add that function into  Socialbar helper class and after that with use of that helper you can call that function.

Comment: `$categoryChild = Mage::("Your_helper_class_name")->getCustomMenuCategory($parentCategoryId);` just like this

Comment: This shows an error when I login to my admin panel `Cannot use try without catch or finally in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Magik/Socialbar/Helper/Data.php on line 14` @ARVIND KARKAR

Comment: Sorry,  $categoryChild = Mage::helper("Your_helper_class_name")->getCustomMenuCategory($par‌​entCategoryId); try this. Sorry once again